# Using Nokogiri to find element before another element

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I have a partial HTML document:

```
<h2>Destinations</h2>
<div>It is nice <b>anywhere</b> but here.
<ul>
  <li>Florida</li>
  <li>New York</li>
</ul>
<h2>Shopping List</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Booze</li>
  <li>Bacon</li>
</ul>
```

On every `<li>` item, I want to know the category the item is in, e.g., the text in the `<h2>` tags.

This code does not work, but this is what I'm trying to do:

```
@page.search('li').each do |li|
  li.previous('h2').text
end
```

Comment: It would be the h2 previous to the parent of the li, not previous to the li, no?

Comment: I don't really know how many elements would be between the h2 and the li; I just want to know how to find the h2 before the li I've found using the Mechanize search.

Comment: You're doing it backwards, instead of iterating the `li`'s and trying to get the preceding `h2`, iterate the `h2`'s and then get the `li`'s

Comment: @pguardiario nailed it. Search for `<h2>` tags then look at the next sibling and use it to descend to the `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokogiri allows you to use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expressions to locate an element:

```
categories = []

doc.xpath("//li").each do |elem|
  categories << elem.parent.xpath("preceding-sibling::h2").last.text
end

categories.uniq!
p categories
```

The first part looks for all "li" elements, then inside, we look for the parent (ul, ol), the for an element before ([preceding-sibling](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)) which is an h2. There can be more than one, so we take the last (ie, the one closest to the current position).

We need to call "uniq!" as we get the h2 for each 'li' (as the 'li' is the starting point).

Using your own HTML example, this code output:

```
["Destinations", "Shopping List"]
```

Comment: Since it's actually the li elements that I'm interested in, is there a way to go back until the h2 is found, or double up the preceding-element directives? Or, do I have to program to from the ul and go up, then a loop for all the li elements in the ul?

Comment: What's the advantage of using the li ? You do have an ul around, and it's a single one. It could work with the li, but you'll have a lot of repetition

Comment: The OP has their own reasons for specifying the need for the `<li>` tags. Perhaps they want to be able to insert additional content in them?

Comment: Updated the best I could

Comment: This worked well. Thank you also for including the link to the XPath Axes tutorial; I'd tried searching Nokogiri and Mechanize documentation and couldn't find where you were getting "preceding-sibling" from.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

```
@page.search('li').each do |li|
  category = li.xpath('../preceding-sibling::h2').text
  puts "#{li.text}: category #{category}" 
end
```

Answer (score -2):

**The code:**

```
categories = []
Nokogiri::HTML("yours HTML here").css("h2").each do |category|
        categories << category.text
      end
```

**The result:**

```
categories = ["Destinations", "Shopping List"]
```

Comment: Why not explain WHY this works, rather than just throw out some code hoping the OP figures it out? Our job as answerers is really to educate, not just solve the immediate problem.

Comment: Use `categories = Nokogiri::HTML("yours HTML here").css("h2").map(&:text)` instead.